# Getting "The reference to entity must end with the ';' delimiter" error, but I can't use &amp; or %26 in place of &

Tags: java, javascript, json, servlets, jsonp

I'm developing a webpage which runs a script that calls a servlet, and the mode of data transfer is in JSONP.

The script is something like this:

```
    $.ajax({
        url : http://mywebsite.com/Servlet/ServletName?args1=AA&args2=BBB&args3=111&callback=?,
        type : 'get',
        dataType : 'jsonp',
        success : function(res) {
            // do stuff to process the response
        },
        error : function(e, msg) {
            // log the error
        }
    });
```

But when I run it, I get an error in my system log as follows:

```
The reference to entity "args1" must end with the ';' delimiter.
```

So in place of "&", I tried "&amp;" and "%26", but those both didn't work because apparently, when the servlet receives the request, this is what happens:

```
args1 = AA&args2=BBB&args3=111&callback=?
args2 = null
args3 = null
```

Obviously what I want is this:

```
args1 = AA
args2 = BBB
args3 = 111
```

But it seems like "&amp;" and "%26" aren't able to parse the arguments correctly. Is there anything else I can try to resolve this problem?

Comment: "callback=?"   i think this is wrong.
it should be "callback=someFunction"

Comment: The callback is randomly generated by JQuery, if I'm not mistaken.

Comment: Would it help to use the Javascript built-in function `encodeURI()`?

Comment: thanks for the suggestion sherb, but it seems as though I found a solution... I put the embedded javascript in a .js file separate from the html and then included the script in the html instead. For some reason, that worked. The system is not complaining about the "&" anymore.